# How do I compare each element of a list using elem?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am trying to use the elem function to compare every element of a list with another list. So far I have

```
compin:: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
compin (x:xs) ys = elem x ys
```

this seems to only apply the function to the first element of the first list. how do I compare each element of the first list to the whole of the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

`compin xs ys = all (flip elem ys) xs`

?

Short and easy.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on what you want to do. Possible answers are:

```
compin (x:xs) ys = elem x ys && compin xs ys   -- ensure every xs is in ys

compin (x:xs) ys = elem x ys || compin xs ys   -- check if at least on xs is in ys
```

Both have different base cases - you have to decide what happends when `xs` is the empty list:

```
compin [] ys = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use some form of recursion.  To do it with explicit recursion, you could do

```
compin [] ys = True
compin (x:xs) ys = elem x ys && compin xs ys
```

However, it could be done more simply using `map` and `foldr`:

```
--                               v What we do with each element of x
compin xs ys = foldr (&&) True $ map (`elem` ys) xs
--                    ^    ^ Base case for xs == []
--                    | The operation we perform between each iteration
```

But this is also a common pattern:

```
compin xs ys = and $ map (`elem` ys) xs
-- and xs = foldr (&&) True xs
```

But this can be reduced one more time:

```
compin xs ys = all (`elem` ys) xs
-- all p xs = and $ map p xs
```

The `and` and `all` functions are defined already in `Prelude`.  This would check if every `x` is in `ys`.  If you want to check if any `x` is in `ys`, then replace `&&` with `||, replace`and`with`or`, and replace`all`with`any`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the set operations in Data.List

```
> a = [1..5]
> b = [2,3]
> b \\ a
[]
```

empty list will mean `b` is contained in `a`.  Assumes list elements are unique though.